# How to install LLVMgold.so for clang+llvm binary package?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, clang++, llvm-clang

I would like to use llvm control flow integrity and I used the clang+llvm binary packaged version 7.0.1 shipped for Ubuntu 14.04. When I use clang++ with options '-fsanitize=cfi -flto -fvisibility=hidden' I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/username/llvm-7.0.1/bin/../lib/LLVMgold.so: error loading plugin: /home/username/llvm-7.0.1/bin/../lib/LLVMgold.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any idea how can I fix that without compiling the source code with option that enables gold?

Comment: I wasn't able to. Just built from source (which wasn't as bad as it sounds)

Answer (score 2):

I received a similar error when linking with `clang 13.0.0-2`.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/../lib/LLVMgold.so: error loading plugin: /usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/../lib/LLVMgold.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I ran `apt search` for `llvmgold` and found `llvm-13-linker-tools` recommended. Installing this made the issue go away.

```
sudo apt-get install llvm-13-linker-tools
```

I got `clang` simply via `sudo apt-get install clang`. Try looking for the `llvm-7` equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with recently llvm version 10. it seems not a bug of llvm, so would not patched in the future. so, I wrotten here how to fix this.

after build the llvm, you should ran the `make install` command. but LLVMgold.so installed to '/usr/local/lib' typically. therefore clang show message like this '/../lib/LLVMgold.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'

you must link LLVMgold to right path. in ubuntu, 'ln -sf /usr/lib/llvm-3.4/lib/LLVMgold.so /usr/local/lib/LLVMgold.so' will fix this.

Comment: Is there a way to install LLVMgold.so without compiling LLVM yourself?

Answer (score -2):

I received a similar error warning when trying to compile Python from sources with `--with-lto` option on Ubuntu 14. The easiest thing to do was to just remove the `--with-lto` flag during configuration.